# How should I pass a computed object from the primary class constructor to the supertype constructor?

Tags: scala, macros

I'm working in a Scala 2.12 macro context.

All the constructor fields are dynamically discovered, there's no potential to hardcode them inside the quasiquote.

The desired outcome (stripped down to the minimal demonstrable example) is code like this:

```
 case class A2(i: Int) extends A(B(i))
```

Where B is constructed inline in the invocation of the super constructor.

I have this:

```
q"case class ${className.toTypeName}(..$fields) extends $superTypeType(..$superConstructorArgs)")
```

I hoped to establish $superConstructorArgs from $fields in this manner:

```
case q"case class $className(..$fields) extends ..$bases { ..$body }" => {
        val superConstructorArgs = B(fields.map{case v:ValDef => ???
```

The compiler wants a Tree instead of a B to be inserted into the supertype constructor.

What's the right sort of Tree to go around my B and how should it be built?

Answer (score 0):

With some embarrassment I report back for posterity:

The missing code is

```
v.name
```

That's the required element to be folded back into the super constructor as it's invoked in quasiquotation.